# Fill and iterate a vector of 100 ints faster than 1 ints

Tags: c++, vector

I'm reading about [std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now) And when look at the example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <chrono>

volatile int sink;
int main()
{
    for (auto size = 1ull; size < 1000000000ull; size *= 100) {
        // record start time
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        // do some work
        std::vector<int> v(size, 42);
        sink = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0u); // make sure it's a side effect
        // record end time
        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end-start;
        std::cout << "Time to fill and iterate a vector of " 
                  << size << " ints : " << diff.count() << " s\n";
    }
}
```

the results I get are a little weird:

Time to fill and iterate a vector of 1 ints : 4.954e-06 s

Time to fill and iterate a vector of 100 ints : 2.858e-06 s

Time to fill and iterate a vector of 10000 ints : 0.000109001 s

Why is the case 100 elements faster?

Comment: Tell us, is `std::high_resolution_clock::is_steady` true or false?

Comment: probably to do with the caching. On the 1st iteration nothing is in the cache so you get a cache miss, and then it has to go off load a block in memory. 2nd iteration where you fill 100 ints it can use the cached location.

Comment: std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::is_steady= false;

Comment: Not necessarily. It's just that `high_resolution_clock` may not be appropriate for these measurements. Try `steady_clock`.

Comment: @sashang :probably, when initialized 2 times,
 Time to fill and iterate a vector of 1 ints : 3.8937e-05 s
 Time to fill and iterate a vector of 1 ints : 4.76e-07 s
 Time to fill and iterate a vector of 100 ints : 1.61e-06 s